# Low level rendering functionality in Blender's API

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

While all Blender functionality is exposed through operators, their indirect way of acquiring data for a certain task is tedious. Especially when the data we want them to operate on is acquired programmatically. Luckily, most tasks can be achieved with lower level parts of the API; with data directly given to functions as arguments. For example using `object.modifiers.new(name = 'Bevel', type = 'BEVEL')`instead of `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type = 'BEVEL')` (the modifier is added to the object on which the method is called (`object`), not to the active object).

My question is, is there low-level functionality for (Cycles) rendering and baking in the API? I have noticed the `RenderEngine` class ([Docs > Types > RenderEngine](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html?highlight=render)), but I'm not sure whether it's a class exposing the functionality of Cycles or some other Blender's render engine. Is there a way to do the same as `bpy.ops.render.render` and `bpy.ops.render.bake` operators do; not with the context data, but with neccesary data passed in. Is it possible? If there is, an example or an overview of it would be much appreciated.

If there isn't, what is the best way to tackle the problem? How should I modify and override the context on which the operators then operate with my own objects in the code?

I'd also like to point out, I'm neither experienced with Python or Blender API. Have started learning about the API a few days ago and been picking up Python along the way. I am a long time Blender user and am also somewhat proficient in Java. Thank you for reading my question; if you know the answer or can correct a mistake or a misconception in my question, I'd greatly appreciate it if you did.

Comment: `RenderEngine` class can be used to implement third party engines e.g. [luxrender](https://github.com/LuxCoreRender/BlendLuxCore). Short answer is: *No*. However, probably it's me don't understanding *"your problem"*... What exactly you'd like to do?

Comment: @brockmann To be more specific, I'd like to bake normals from a dictionary of high-low objects (that I get from a function) and save the results. As already described, I'd prefer to do it without the use of operators. Perhaps I should also mention I intend on using the tool for batch baking textures from preprepared .blend files with high and low poly meshes (it would preferably be run from the command line).